# Python3 decode removes white spaces when should be kept

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, pycharm, decode

I'm reading a binary file that has a code on STM32. I placed deliberate 2 const strings in the code, that allows me to read SW version and description from a given file.

When you open a binary file with hex editor or even in python3, you can see correct form. But when run `text = data.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')`, it removes a zeros from the file! I don't want this, as I keep EOL characters to properly split and extract string that interest me.

(preview of the end of the data variable)

> Svc\x00..\Src\adc.c\x00..\Src\can.c\x00defaultTask\x00Task_CANbus_receive\x00Task_LED_Controller\x00Task_LED1_TX\x00Task_LED2_RX\x00Task_PWM_Controller\x00**SW_VER:GN_1.01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00MODULE_DESC:generic_module\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00**Task_SuperVisor_Controller\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x06\x07\x08\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04..\Src\tim.c\x005!\x00\x08\x11!\x00\x08\x01\x00\x00\x00\xaa\xaa\xaa\xaa\x01\x01\nd\x00\x02\x04\nd\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa2J\x04'

(preview of text, i.e. what I receive after decode)

> r g         @   IDLE TmrQ Tmr Svc ..\Src\adc.c ..\Src\can.c
>   defaultTask Task_CANbus_receive Task_LED_Controller Task_LED1_TX
>   Task_LED2_RX Task_PWM_Controller SW_VER:GN_1.01
>   MODULE_DESC:generic_module
>   Task_SuperVisor_Controller                ..\Src\tim.c 5! !
>       d  d    J

```
with open(path_to_file, "rb") as binary_file:
    # Read the whole file at once
    data = binary_file.read()
    text = data.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')

    # get index of "SW_VER:" sting in the file
    sw_ver_index = text.rfind("SW_VER:")
    # SW_VER found
    if sw_ver_index is not -1:
        # retrive the value, e.g. "SW_VER:WB_2.01" will has to start from position 7 and finish at 14
        sw_ver_value = text[sw_ver_index + 7:sw_ver_index + 14]
        module.append(tuple(('DESC:', sw_ver_value)))
    else:
    # SW_VER not found
        module.append(tuple(('DESC:', 'N/A')))


    # get index of "MODULE_DESC::" sting in the file
    module_desc_index = text.rfind("MODULE_DESC:")
    # MODULE_DESC found
    if module_desc_index is not -1:
        module_desc_substring = text[module_desc_index + 12:]
        module_desc_value = module_desc_substring.split()
        module.append(tuple(('DESC:', module_desc_value[0])))
        print(module_desc_value[0])
```

As you can see my white characters are gone, while they should be present

Comment: I don't quite see what exactly is missing. The input and output don't match, but that's mostly because you use `print()` to output them – control characters like the null bytes (`"\x00"`) aren't visible then. Also, if you do something like `decode('utf-8', errors="ignore")`, you are prone to losing information, since any non-UTF-8 bytes will be dropped.